# Where do I find a toothbrush?

Tags: untitled-goose-game

For the "Go Shopping" objective I need to collect a toothbrush, but I can't seem to find one. I assume it would be in the little shop, but it doesn't seem to be.

Where can I find the toothbrush to complete the "Go Shopping" objective?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The toothbrush is located in the trashcan, which is in the top right section of this stage. You'll have to knock the trash can over before plundering its contents.